# How can ethereum token use as payment gateway on ecommerce website

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have problem that if I created ethereum token and I want to use it in real project . especially in payment gateway . How can integrate ethereum token as payment in ecommerce website and how can develope as android wallet from ethereum token solidity codes.
plz guide me.